# Trying to use async/await

Tags: javascript, .net, google-maps, async-await

EDITED:

Getting coordinates and distance using Google Maps API. Working fine but, when I try to send these datas to my controller, using Ajax, those datas are null.

So, I started to use await/async function. After that and some helps, I am getting all data from Google, but still getting null datas at my controller (Lat, Lng and Distance). Other values from my inputs are ok.

My JavasScript code:

```
    $("#btnConfirm").click(async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _this = $(this);
        var _form = _this.closest("form");
        var isvalid = _form.valid();
        if (isvalid) {

            await GetLatLngGoogle($('#address').val()); 
            ^^^^
            
            await GetDistance();
            ^^^^

            AddAddress();
        }
    });

   async function GetLatLngGoogle(address) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address },
                function (results, status) {
                    $("#Lat").val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    $("#Lng").val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                });
            resolve('resolved');
        });
    };

    var map = null;
    var start = null;
    var end = null;
    var directionsService = null;
    var directionsDisplay = null;

    async function GetDistance() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.71620968890981, -74.08542546242037);
            var clientPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(40.70550895916085, -74.0791867502397);
            var storePosition = { lat: 40.71620968890981, lng: -74.08542546242037 };
    
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

            var route = {
                origin: storePosition ,
                destination: clientPosition,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            directionsService.route(route, RenderCustomDirections);
            resolve('resolved');
       });
    };

    async function RenderCustomDirections(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            start = new Object();
            end = new Object();
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    start.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
                    start.address = legs[i].start_address;
                }
                end.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
                end.address = legs[i].end_address;
            }
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());

        } else alert(status);
    };

    async function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        let total = 0;
        let timeTotal = 0;
        const myroute = result.routes[0];

        if (!myroute) {
            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
            total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
            timeTotal += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
        }
        total = total / 1000;
        timeTotal = timeTotal / 60;
        $('#Distance').val(total.toFixed(1));
    };

function AddAddress() {
    var options = {};
    options.type = "POST";
    options.url = "/api/AddAddress";
    options.dataType = "JSON";
    options.cache = false;
    options.async = true;
    contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        options.data = $('#formAdd').serialize();

    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    };

    options.success = function (data) {

    };

    options.error = function () {
        
    };
    $.ajax(options);
};
```

My Html:

```
<form id="formAdd">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnConfirm">
         Confirm
    </button>
              ...

    <input asp-for="Lat" value="@Model.Lat" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="Lng" value="@Model.Lng" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="Distance" value="@Model.Distance" type="hidden" />

  </form>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx"></script>
<script src="~/js/app/addressAddAddress.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `await GetLatLngGoogle($('#address').val()); // working fine` You never resolve the promise in `GetLatLngGoogle`. Which consequently is why the rest of the code doesn't work because the `await`ed value never resolves. You have the same problem with `GetDistance()` - the promise is never resolved.

Comment: A little tip!!,  Try and avoid Promise Constructor pattern for general use.   Eg. If say a third party lib has only callbacks and doesn't use promises, (I'm surprised if google Api are not using them by now).  I would create a wrapper function for the callback, and then this avoids  having the Promise Contructor pattern littering your codebase.  IOW:  `new Promise(...)` should be a rare thing  to see in any codebase.

Comment: How to resolve? I need the pass a return value? @VLAZ

Comment: Do not instantiate your map in the GetDistance function. This will lead to a charge on every call for the Dynamic Maps SKU.

Comment: When I put a setTimeOut() inside each function works fine. setTimeout(() => { resolve('resolved'); }, 3000);.  But I dont want to user setTimeOut.